# How refactor two methods which are very similar

Tags: java, refactoring

I have following classes:

```
public interface IBaseInterface {
    String baseMethod();
}

public class BaseClass implements IBaseInterface{

    @Override
    public String baseMethod() {
        return "baseInterface";
    }

    public String otherBaseMethod(){
        return "otherBaseMethod";
    }

}

public class ClassA implements IBaseInterface{

    @Override
    public String baseMethod() {
        return "ClassA";
    }

    public String getAttribiuteA(){
        return "A";
    }

}

public class ClassB implements IBaseInterface {

    @Override
    public String baseMethod() {
        return "ClassB";
    }

    public String getAttribiuteB(){
        return "B";
    }

}
```

And now I have two very similar methods:

```
private String getBaseMethod(){

    /** Do something */

    if(/**    */){
        BaseClass base = new BaseClass();
        return base.baseMethod();
    }else if (/**    */){
        ClassA a = new ClassA();
        return a.baseMethod();
    } else {
        ClassB b = new ClassB();
        return b.baseMethod();
    }
}

private String getOtherMethod(){

    /** Do something */

    if(/**    */){
        BaseClass base = new BaseClass();
        if(/**    */){
            return base.baseMethod();
        } else{
            return base.otherBaseMethod()
        }
    } else if(/**    */){
        ClassA a = new ClassA();
        return a.getAttribiuteA()
    } else{
        ClassB b = new ClassB();
        return b.getAttribiuteB();
    }
}
```

These two methods are very similar. In if-Clause are the same conditions. Can we make these two methods better? More "abstractly" ?

I can not make any changes in my classes, only in methods.

Comment: what is your purpose for both methods anyway? why do you have them in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

I assume what is being asked here is to use 'Polymorphism'

Because all three classes, BaseClass, ClassA, and ClassB, all implement interfcae IBaseInterface, so you can do such thing like following example:

```
 IBaseInterface i1 = new BaseClass();
 IBaseInterface i2 = new ClassA();
 IbaseInterface i3 = new ClassB();
```

And as you already noticed at this point, you may use List to save your classes too.

```
 List<IBaseInterface> interfaces = new ArrayList<>();
 interfaces.add(i1);
 ....
```

and so on

Because IBaseInterface has method baseMethod(), now you can simply iterate through the list and invoke baseMethod() method for each IBaseInterface objects.

take a look for 'Polymorphic Behavior'

Comment: Ok, but how invoke method getAttribiuteA() and getAttribiuteB() ? These methods are only in ClassA and ClassB, so polymorpgic doesn't work...

Comment: If you need to invoke those methods, you will need to cast it. There is no easier way to do it. For example, you can use 'instance of' to check if the object is which class. (i2 instanceof ClassA) will return true because i2 is a instance(or Object) of ClassA. Then, you can invoke getAttributeA() by ((ClassA) i2).getAttributeA().You are casting i2 to ClassA and invoking its method 'getAttributeA().' It is essential to use 'instanceof' as the object in the IBaseInterface variable can be any class that implements IBaseInterface interface.